# How do I define an event for a point click in a chart series?

Tags: excel, vba, events, series, excel-charts

I have a chart (scatter with smooth lines and markers) containing six series.  The series all share the same X values.  On the same sheet, I have one column of X values and six columns of Y values, one for each series (all series share the same X values).  The user needs to be able to smooth small irregularities in the Y values.  Ideally, the user would simply click a point directly on the chart and drag it up (to increase the Y value) or down (to decrease the Y value). But since that is impossible AFAIK, the second best solution would be for the user to click the point and have VBA select the cell containing the corresponding Y value. My question is: How do I define an event for the point click which I can capture in a VBA handler?  The handler can then decode the point information, determine sheet cell, and select it.

Comment: https://peltiertech.com/chart-events-microsoft-excel/

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to peltiertech.com.  It has exactly what I was looking for.